# How to pick capital letters from a Swift string?

Tags: ios, string, swift

I need capital letters from a string. With `NSString` it was sth like:

```
for (var i = 0; i<str.length; i++) {

    let c = str.characterAtIndex(i)

    if c >= 'A' && c < 'Z' {
        //..
    }
}
```

In Swift it starts like:

```
for (var i = 0; i<countElements(str); i++) {
    //..
}
```

But I do not know i.e. how to pick i-th character, I am checking [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/StringsAndCharacters.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example this work fine in Swift :

```
var st = "Hello World"

for ch in st {
   if ch >= "A" && ch <= "Z"{
      println(ch)
   }
}
```

And print

```
H
W
```

Or you could this instead :

```
var range = "A"..."Z"

for ch in st {
   if range.contains(String(ch)) {
      println(ch)
  }
}
```

Or the solution of @Gabrielle updated to **Swift 2.0**:

```
func capitalLetters(s: String) -> [Character] {
    return s.characters.filter { ("A"..."Z").contains($0) }
}

capitalLetters("fOo BAr") // ["O", "B", "A"]
```

Comment: @János this http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-strings/ could help a lot understading Strings in Swift.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a slightly more idiomatic version in swift

```
func capitalLetters(s: String) -> [Character] {
    return filter(s) { ("A"..."Z").contains($0) }
}

capitalLetters("fOo BAr") // ["O", "B", "A"]
```

or even:

```
func capitalLetters(s: String) -> [Character] {
    func isCapital(c: Character) -> Bool {
        return ("A"..."Z").contains(c)
    }
    return filter(s, isCapital)
}

capitalLetters("fOo BAr")
```

or also, you could make the syntax nicer by providing an extension

```
extension String {
    func capitalLetters() -> [Character] {
        func isCapital(c: Character) -> Bool {
            return ("A"..."Z").contains(c)
        }
        return filter(self, isCapital)
    }
}

"fOo BAr".capitalLetters()
```

Comment: You actually don't need to make `s` an `Array` first if you use the global `filter` function, and you can use a range to make it a bit more concise: `filter("fOo BAr") { ("A"..."Z").contains($0) }`